# What do these two METAR codes mean?

Tags: metar

> METAR YPJT 070300Z AUTO 10010KT 9999 // NCD 27/10 Q1018 RMK
> RF00.0/000.0

In the above METAR report, I have two questions:

1. What does the fraction "27/10" mean?
2. What does "RF00.0/000.0" also mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term **27/10** is the temperature (27°C) and dew point (10°C).

The **RF** term in the remark section is used to indicate the accumulated rainfall (in this case 0, so no rain):

> **What is the meaning of the RF group in METAR/SPECI and TTF?**
>
> This group reports rainfall in the last ten minutes and accumulated rainfall since 0900 local. For example, RF02.2/024.4 reports that 2.2mm of rainfall has fallen in the 10 minutes prior to the report time; and 24.4mm has fallen since 0900 local.

<sup>([Australian Government - Bureau of Meteorology](http://www.bom.gov.au/aviation/about-us/faq/))</sup>